# DB2 9.7 fails to install with Segmentation fault

Tags: db2, installation, fault

when I install DB2v9.7 on my ubuntu10.04-64bit,error below:

**Segmentation fault**

only this two words,I had no idea how to solve it.

I use the silent method ,when I execute sudo ./db2setup -r db2ese.rsp , error comes.

Comment: @dan1111 He could be using [`Express-C`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/db2express/index.html), which is free.

Comment: I don't think that Ubuntu 10.04 is supported with DB2 9.7.  If you are using Express-C, and want to use Ubuntu 10.04, then try downloading DB2 v10.1, which supports Ubuntu 10.04. [System Requirements for v10.1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0008865.html)

Comment: This might be relevant (sorry, didn't know about the free version) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC67897

Comment: I'm sure that DB2 v9.7 can be installed on ubuntu10.04,because I have done it on another vm.I'm using the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved!
It must be maintain symmetry between hostname and the content of /etc/hosts,
my hostname is ubuntu,so I add one line in /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1    ubuntu
It works! 
Thanks for all help me !
Alex

Comment: Thanks for writing back on how you solved the problem. I had this exact problem (on RHEL 6.0). It seems the problem occurs on creation of the DB2 instance, segfaults without warning or explanation. Adding the hostfile entry worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is DB2 successfully installed on the machine and you are getting segmentation fault while starting DB2 instance? Or you are seeing the error while starting the v9.7 installer only.. please clear this..

If you are hitting this while starting the installer then please run the install utility again with -t  option and send the trace file to db2.luw@gmail.com. I wll get back to you asap.

If you are hitting the error while starting db2 instance then attach the db2diag.log file.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer. You should comment a question or an answer to elaborate on someting and add an answer to the quesion once you can actually answer the question.

Comment: I install the db2 silently,when I execute : sudo ./db2setup -r db2ese.rsp ,only about 3 seconds later ,it print : Segmentation fault ,no other words . I have installed the same db2 successfully on a another ubuntu 10.04 machine ,use the same db2 package,same response and same installation method.

Comment: Kindly provide the trace/log and response file. Without these its very difficult to find out the where the problem is.